# C sizeof char pointer

Tags: c, pointers, char, sizeof

Why is size of this char variable equal 1?

```
int main(){

char s1[] = "hello";

fprintf(stderr, "(*s1) : %i\n", sizeof(*s1) )    // prints out 1

}
```

Comment: `sizeof(char) = 1`, `*` is value at address operator. `*s` is nothing but first char. that is in your case `h`. so `sizeof(*s)=1`, interesting is sizeof(s1) is `6`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan ASCII has `128` codes not `256`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Do you know about extended ASCII chart? its upto 256 that is 0 to 255...

Comment: I think that C don't know about the extended ASCII chart.

Comment: The operator `sizeof` yields a value of type `size_t`. Even ignoring the fact that you're calling a "variadic" function without a prototype in scope, using `"%i"` without a corresponding `int` argument is wrong. Either use `"%zu"` or cast the value. Oh! and include the proper header.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

NOTA: the original question has changed a little bit at first it was: *why is the size of this char pointer 1*

`sizeof(*s1)`

is the same as

`sizeof(s1[0])` which is the size of a `char` object and not the size of a `char` pointer.

The size of an object of type `char` is always `1` in C.

To get the size of the `char` pointer use this expression: `sizeof (&s1[0])`

Answer (score 7):

> **Why is size of this char variable equal 1?**

Because size of a `char` is guaranteed to be `1` byte by the C standard.

```
*s1 == *(s1+0) == s1[0] == char
```

If you want to get size of a character pointer, you need to pass a character pointer to `sizeof`:

```
sizeof(&s1[0]);
```

Answer (score 5):

Because you are deferencing the pointer decayed from the array `s1` so you obtain the value of the first pointed element, which is a `char` and `sizeof(char) == 1`.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(*s1)` means "the size of the element pointed to by `s1`". Now `s1` is an array of `char`s, and when treated as a pointer (it "decays into" a pointer), dereferencing it results in a value of type `char`.

And, `sizeof(char)` is **always one.** The C standard requires it to be so.

If you want the size of the whole array, use `sizeof(s1)` instead.

Comment: `sizeof(s1)` returns size including `\0` and I think that he don't want it.

Comment: @Jack Yes, it does. Who cares? One should be aware of `strlen()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sizeof(*s1) means its denotes the size of data types which used. In C there are 1 byte used by character data type that means sizeof(*s1) it directly noticing to the character which consumed only 1 byte.

If there are any other data type used then the **sizeof(*data type)** will be changed according to type.
```